# View.onRestoreInstanceState not being called when fragment setRetainInstance(true) (double screen orientation change when fragment is in a back stack)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have two fragments: one on top of another. Fragments has `setRetainInstance(true)` in their constructors.

When I do a double screen flip and press back key, top fragment gets popped and bottom fragment becomes visible. But bottom fragment's view do not receive `onRestoreInstanceState`.

When I remove `setRetainInstance(true)` everything works just fine. But I need that `setRetainInstance(true)` to work with multiple threads, so I can't solve my problem that simple. :)

How to guarantee `onRestoreInstanceState` to be called in this case?

Here is some example code:

```
package com.example.saverestoreviewstate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new Fragment1()).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class SaveRestoreView extends TextView {

        public SaveRestoreView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        String value;

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
            setText(value);
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("super", super.onSaveInstanceState());
            bundle.putString("value", value);
            return bundle;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
            Bundle bundle = (Bundle)state;
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable("super"));
            value = bundle.getString("value");
            setText(value);
        }
    }

    public static class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

        private static boolean firstRun = true;

        public Fragment1() {
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Context context = inflater.getContext();

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
            layout.setId(12);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            SaveRestoreView saveRestore = new SaveRestoreView(context);
            saveRestore.setId(128);

            if (firstRun) {
                saveRestore.setValue("*******save this string*******");
                firstRun = false;
            }

            layout.addView(saveRestore);

            Button button = new Button(inflater.getContext());
            button.setText("Create 2nd fragment");
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new Fragment2()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            });

            layout.addView(button);

            return layout;
        }
    }

    public static class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

        public Fragment2() {
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return new View(inflater.getContext());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've finished implementing save/restore logic manually.
The minus is that I can't turn off save\restore that already exist, so `onSaveInstance`/`onRestoreInstance` is called twice on a View. Except of that one time when it is not called by itself - then it IS called once B-).

To make it work just add to `Fragment1` class:

```
    SparseArray<Parcelable> savedState;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if (savedState != null)
            view.restoreHierarchyState(savedState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        savedState = new SparseArray<Parcelable>();
        getView().saveHierarchyState(savedState);
    }
```